# Delete Event from FullCalendar and also Django

Tags: django, fullcalendar

Looking for a bit of direction after struggling to find anything googling..

I have implemented full calendar.io using django to store the events.

I can show the events and when the events are clicked, they open a modal, showing the data for that event.

In this modal, I want to include a delete button, I can pass the id of the event from django to the modal but I cannot figure out how to delete the entry from the django dB when the delete button is clicked..

Can someone please help?

Any direction would be appreciated!

Comment: you'd need to post a form back or make an ajax call to the server and pass the ID of the event you want to delete

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using a form to this